# Cleanup consumer groups after topic deletion

Tags: apache-kafka

I am facing an issue when deleting a topic with active consumers subscribed to it. After deleting the topic, some consumer groups keep their offsets even after the group manager of each broker clean up the group metadata (this [code](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/2e0f9f42ddc287802690410d00ec3590cca7d28d/core/src/main/scala/kafka/coordinator/group/GroupCoordinator.scala#L1101), which deletes offsets of every groupId regardless of its status). If the topic is then re-created for any reason, consumers will skip all messages from zero to their previous offset.
Is there a critical phase where a consumer could resend its previous position to the coordinator which then re-push it to the consumer_offset partition?

We noticed that most of the time, the problem occurs for consumer groups that have consumers with a long idle between polls (60 seconds), which may overwrite the previous delete offsets action of the coordinator when the consumers wake up from the idle (I supposed they could sync their old offsets).

To avoid the problem we may:

- Ask consumers to unsubscribe from the topic to delete
- Wait sometime
- Use the offsets delete API to delete each offset of each consumer group
- Delete the topic

or

- Ask consumers to unsubscribe from the topic to delete
- Wait sometime
- Delete the topic and rely on the existing mechanism of the coordinators to clean up the consumer groups

But as it should already work with the current implementation of Kafka, do you see any cause for this issue and a better alternative to solve it ?
Is there an advantage to using the delete offset API in addition to the existing delete topic mechanism?

Thank you

Comment: Groups can be subscribed to multiple topics... You can only remove certain topics from `__consumer_offsets` records by having consumers unsubscribe from them, then commit new offsets for the still-existing topics. Otherwise, it's just metadata, so what issues are you running into having it stay around? In other words, if the topic is deleted, and consumers are still trying to read it, they'll get `UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION` **warnings**, not fatal errors and crash...

Comment: Oops, my message was not complete. I edited my initial message. I forgot to mention that the deleted topic is later re-created and the consumers will not read any records while the partitions offset are lower than the previous offset of the consumers (which should be deleted).

Comment: Okay, so in that case, `auto.offset.reset` will take affect when previously found committed offsets are out-of-range.

Comment: I have the same problem. The consumer never reset its offset, this parameter seems to only work with expired offsets but not to solve the offsets of subscriptions on older topics

Comment: Kafka doesnt know if topics are "new/old". If you re-create with the same name, and the topic offset for the found group are out-of-range, then that property should take affect

Comment: what happens if found offsets are in range though? let's say my consumer has offset 50 with `poll(60000)` and the topic gets deleted. the consumer runs into a warning, then the topic is re-created and immediately filled with 60 records before the next `poll()` is invoked by the consumer. as far as i understand, the consumer will now only receive 10 records in the next poll cycle, as the offset 50 is stored and valid. is there any way to handle this automatically rather than to reset offsets manually via CLI tools?